# $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb N, \leq_{lex}) \cong (\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z, \leq_{lex}) $ - order preserving isomorphism between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$1.$ $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb N, \leq_{lex}) \cong (\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z, \leq_{lex}) $

My solution:

$1.$
$(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb N, \leq_{lex}) := (\cdots 
 (-10,0),(-9,0) \cdots (0,0) \cdots (0,100) \cdots (1,0) 
 \cdots)$
$\space(\mathbb N \times \mathbb Z, \leq_{lex}) := (\cdots 
 (0,-10),(0,-9) \cdots (0,0) \cdots (0,100) \cdots (1,0) 
 \cdots)$

There are no min and max items , there are successor and
predecessor for each item.

Like the previous excercises i dont know how i am supposed
to prove it formally.

Comment: What is the predecessor of $(0, 0)$ in $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: You are right ! Thank you !